# Transform and merge tuples in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

I have a list of tuples, like

```
list_of_tuples = [('265', 'U. S.', '', '425'), ('265', 'U. S.', 'at', '435'), ('265', 'U. S.', '', '425'),  ('265', 'U. S.', 'at', '435'), ('537', 'Fed. Appx.', '', '326')]
```

Eventually I want to get this results:

```
[('265 U.S. 425', 4), ('537 Fed. Appx. 326', 1)]
```

that the first element of the tuple is a concatenation of the element 1, 2, and 4 (notice as long as the first two elements in the original tuple are the same, those two tuples should be thought as one - thus the total count for 265 U.S. should be four, and we use 425 because it's small than 435)

Any way to achieve this efficiently?

Comment: you mean you want to count tuples that have the same 2 first elements?

Comment: I don't understand "How do I change the second tuple into the first one (meaning '435' -> '425') so I can later count them?". What is your final objective? Count unique combinations of the first two elements? Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: How to deal with the third element?

Comment: So you want to count them, not merge?

Comment: Please include a bit more sample input, and some sample output.

Comment: In response to your update: What do you want to do with the third elements of the `tuple`'s? What's happening to the `tuple`'s with the final element `'435'`? Are the strings in the result supposed to be the elements in the `tuple`'s joined together with spaces?

Comment: for the third element, if it's a '', it should mean the fourth element should not be rewritten; otherwise if it's an 'at' then the fourth element should be rewritten - in this case 435 changed to 425. Yeah the strings in the results should be tuples joined together, after the change of the fourth element

Comment: I wrote my answer based on your explanation that we choose 425 rather than 435 because it's smaller. Could you please clarify whether the third element of the a tuple in the initial list needs to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to count the `tuple`'s by the first two elements of each `tuple`. If so, this should do what you want:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(tup[:2] for tup in list_of_tuples)

print(counts[('265', 'U. S.')])  # 2
```

Once you run that code, `counts` will be a `Counter` (a `dict`-like object) where `counts[two_tuple] = count_of_that_tuple`.

Comment: Hi I added more details

Answer (score 1):

Using your `list_of_tuples`, we run through the list and keep track of how many element 1 and 2 concatenations we see in the `counts` dict. We also keep track of the element 4 values associated with those 1-2 concatenations in `values` dict, so we can calculate the minimum for each at the end. Finally, we print the output in the desired order via list comprehension.

```
counts = {}
values = {}

for tup in list_of_tuples:
    this_tup = ' '.join([tup[0], tup[1]])
    counts[this_tup] = counts.get(this_tup, 0) + 1
    value_set = values.get(this_tup, set())
    value_set.add(tup[3])
    values[this_tup] = value_set

print [(tup, min(values[tup]), count) for (tup, count) in counts.iteritems()]

# Output:
#=> [('265 U. S.', '425', 4), ('537 Fed. Appx.', '326', 1)]
```